# Has Apple indicated that some 2019 MacBook Pros have a fault relating to power, battery or shutdown issues?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, crash, charging, shutdown

I bought a MacBook Pro two days ago and when I was using it for the first time I noticed that when it drops below 40% (20%-40%) it shuts down with no warning and it's impossible to turn it back on unless I plug in the power cable. I thought it must be a hardware issue so I got it replaced for a new one. I set up my new computer and I found out that it had the same issue.

I tried resetting the System Management Controller (SMC) as per Apple's instructions at: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201295

Unfortunately, this didn't resolve the issue.

At this point I think it would be stupid to buy a third MacBook Pro just to find out that it's not working again.

Has anyone come across any information that indicates this is a known issue?

For the record, here is my battery information:

```
  CHARGE INFORMATION:

Charge Remaining (mAh): 5107

 Fully Charged: No(its 100%)

Charging:   Yes

Full Charge Capacity (mAh): 5159

HEALTH INFORMATION:

Cycle Count:    3

Condition:  Normal(1 day old battery)

Battery Installed:  Yes

Amperage (mA):  2439

Voltage (mV):   12516
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) I hope you find this site a valuable source of info/help. I just wanted to let you know I've edited your question as it was at risk of being primarily opinion-based. You may want to take a look at [What topics can I ask about here?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for more clarity. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

At this stage it's **too early** in the product cycle for this model to know if this rates as a known issue for Apple.

However, any product, no matter the type or manufacturer, can have a fault and having bad batches of components is not unheard of. Apple does use warranty extension programs, replacement programs and repair programs if/when it identifies there's a definite issue to address. At this stage though it would be pure speculation, even if a handful of MacBook Pros presented with the same issue.

You indicate you've reset the SMC as per Apple's instructions, but just to be thorough your model MacBook Pro has a T2 chip and you have two options for resetting the SMC (the 2nd to be tried if the first fails).

**Resetting the SMC on a 2019 MacBook Pro**

1. **Fully shut down your MBP.**
2. Press and hold the power button for at least 10 seconds
3. Let go of the power button and wait 5 seconds
4. Power up your MBP again

Once you've reset the SMC fully charge your MBP and see how you go. If it's still misbehaving, reset the SMC again but with the following steps instead:

1. **Fully shut down your MBP.**
2. Press and hold the **right** <kbd>shift</kbd> key and the **left** <kbd>option</kbd> and <kbd>control</kbd> keys for 7 seconds before then also pressing and holding the power button (or Touch ID button) down for another 7 seconds (i.e. the keys will end up being held down for 14 seconds, the power button for 7 seconds)
3. Let go of all three keys and the power button
4. Wait 5 seconds
5. Power up your MBP again

Now test your MBP again.

If the above fails, then I'd be talking to Apple Support to explain what's happening. If they can't address the issue then you're entitled to a refund or replacement, but you'll want to get onto it straight away so that a case is logged this early in your ownership.

Answer (score 1):

You've already taken one machine back and Apple accepted that it was faulty and replaced it: it would **not** be stupid to do the same again if it's exhibiting the same symptoms.

I'd say three Macs in a row would be amazingly rare and unlucky, or it would indeed hint at some significant production fault. Either way, Apple needs to know and get it fixed for you.

Comment: The replacement computer came from a different city.

Comment: Maybe the whole batch is defected.

Comment: They also told me that other people have also had the same issue.

Comment: @Hello Yours is the 3rd case I've heard of with a similar issue, so it *seems* there's a bad batch of *something*. In the meantime they'll just replace/refund the MBPs. Any MBPs returned with this fault will be tested and if/when the numbers are large enough, they'll be able to track down the exact component(s) at fault and the batch number(s) and date ranges. However, if the numbers never get large enough then affected customers shouldn't suffer as they'll get refunds (if reported early enough) or a replacement MBP. As I said in my answer, if the SMC reset doesn't fix it, go back to Apple.